# How can I open mutt messages in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

I'm experimenting with mutt (actually neomutt) and would like to take advantage of org-mode features while composing mail.

I have mutt configured so that I compose my messages in emacs. I'd like to open these messages in org-mode. Is this possible?

Mutt seems to open a tmp file `/tmp/neomutt-whoami-xxxxxxxxxxxx`. Maybe there is a way to write a hook so that files of the form `/tmp/neomutt-whoami*` are always opened in org-mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific case:

```
(add-to-list
 'auto-mode-alist '("\\`/tmp/neomutt-whoami" . org-mode))
```

The initial `` \\` `` in front of `/tmp/...` is necessary to avoid matching paths such as `/foobar/tmp/neomutt-whoami-xxxx`.

Briefly, `auto-mode-alist` is a list of the form:

```
((REGEXP1 . MODEFUNCTION1)
 (REGEXP2 . MODEFUNCTION2)
 ...
)
```

where the `REGEXP`s are to match the full file name and path (imagined to begin with a `` ` `` and end with a `'`) and the `MODEFUNCTION`s are functions to be executed if a match is found. Emacs's inbuilt help (`C-h v RET auto-mode-alist RET` — `describe-variable` `auto-mode-alist`) will give you a more extensive description (and find its current value).

Even more details can be found with `M-x elisp-index-search RET auto-mode-alist` and `M-x emacs-index-search RET auto-mode-alist` (searching the Emacs info manuals).

Answer (score 0):

How are you going to send the messages? Org-mode does not have any facilities for that. You probably want to compose them in `message-mode` but have some org-mode facilities available (e.g. tables). If that is the case, look into `orgtbl-mode`, a minor mode that allows you to manipulate org-tables in other modes, and `orgstruct-mode` or `orgstruct++-mode` (see their doc strings for information) - although I'm under the impression that the latter two are deprecated and are going to disappear (but I'm not at all sure about that: I just remember a conversation on the mailing list, but my memory is not what it used to be. I'll fix this answer if my memory is indeed playing tricks on me).

Comment: Presumably sending is handled by `mutt` , upon closing of the external editor (`emacs` or `emacsclient` in this case). OTOH, using `message-mode` for better handling of quotes and the like, is still a good idea.